# Android app freezing on SQLite db insert

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm running into a really strange issue trying to insert into a local database. I am adding a record to 2 different tables and the first time I add the value it shows up in the list until the activity is destroyed. I can navigate away and come back and the new value is there but when I close the app and clear it from the history it is gone.

The second time I try and enter a value into the database the UI freezes and it doesn't seem to throw any exceptions or give me any ideas of what is going on.

Here's some code.

```
public void addVehicleService(VehicleService service)
{

    SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = getWritableDatabase();
    int serviceId;
    if (serviceExists(service))
    {
        addServicePerformed(service, null, dbWritable);
    }
    else
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(VEHICLE_ID, service.getVehicleId());
        values.put(SERVICE_NAME, service.getServiceName());
        values.put(SERVICE_INTERVAL, service.getInterval());
        values.put(SERVICE_MILEAGE, service.getOdometer());
        values.put(DAYS_TO_NEXT_NOTIFICATION, 0);
        values.put(NOTIFIED, 0);
        values.put(INITIAL_NOTIFICATION_DATE, Utility.FormatDate(Calendar.getInstance()));

        serviceId = (int) dbWritable.insert(VEHICLE_SERVICE_TABLE, null, values);
        if (serviceId != -1)
            addServicePerformed(service, serviceId, dbWritable);
        else
            Log.d("DBTAG", "Error inserting new Service");
    }
}


private boolean serviceExists(VehicleService service)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(VEHICLE_SERVICE_TABLE, new String[]{ID}, VEHICLE_ID + " = ? AND " + SERVICE_NAME + " = ? AND " + SERVICE_INTERVAL + " = ?",
            new String[]{service.getVehicleId().toString(), service.getServiceName(), service.getInterval().toString()}, null, null, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    return count > 0;
}

private void addServicePerformed(VehicleService service, @Nullable Integer serviceId, SQLiteDatabase dbWritable)
{

    if (serviceId == null)
    {
        dbWritable.beginTransaction();
        serviceId = getServiceId(service, dbWritable);
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SERVICE_ID, serviceId);
    values.put(ODOMETER_AT_SERVICE, service.getOdometer());
    values.put(DATE_OF_SERVICE, Utility.FormatDate(service.getDate()));
    values.put(COST_OF_SERVICE, service.getCost());

    dbWritable.insert(SERVICE_PERFORMED_TABLE, null, values);

}
```

I do have some methods that insert into the database and the changes are retained, so I'm really confused as to what's going on.

Comment: Maybe try offloading the work to a background thread/handler?

Comment: @Submersed even if I wait for a couple minutes it never throws the application not responding dialog, but I can still pull down the notifcation bar and everything. It will eventually be moved off the ui thread, but its 2 rows of an insert. It should not take longer than a second even in the worst case

Comment: Try not passing dbWritable in `addServicePerformed(service, null, dbWritable);`. Just create another instance of Sqlitedatabase in `addServicePerformed`. And Move this line `SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = getWritableDatabase();` into else part.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I could have sworn that I tried that, but It appears to be working. Thank you so much, I've spent way to much time on this.. hah.

Comment: @Stampede10343 Great to hear. May I elaborate this more as an answer ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is you are creating an Instance of `SQLiteDatabase` twice in the case If Service exists. `if(serviceExists(service))`.

So I suggest not to pass `dbWritable` as parameter in

`addServicePerformed(service, null, dbWritable);`. Just create a new instance there like

```
private void addServicePerformed(VehicleService service, @Nullable Integer serviceId){
     SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = getWritableDatabase();
}
```

**What happened actually in your codes ?**

Creating an Instance or let's say an Object inside a method won't causes any freezing, Because It's scope will finished after the method finishes executing, But Creating an instance globally, and again instantiating with different method in separate method and re-using the previous one (global instance) in another method May cause the freezing. Not always but May some time. So create instance whenever you need, Don't make conflict on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addVehicleService(VehicleService service)
{

    int serviceId;
    if (serviceExists(service))
    {
        addServicePerformed(service, null);
    }
    else
    {
        SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(VEHICLE_ID, service.getVehicleId());
        values.put(SERVICE_NAME, service.getServiceName());
        values.put(SERVICE_INTERVAL, service.getInterval());
        values.put(SERVICE_MILEAGE, service.getOdometer());
        values.put(DAYS_TO_NEXT_NOTIFICATION, 0);
        values.put(NOTIFIED, 0);
        values.put(INITIAL_NOTIFICATION_DATE, Utility.FormatDate(Calendar.getInstance()));

        serviceId = (int) dbWritable.insert(VEHICLE_SERVICE_TABLE, null, values);
        if (serviceId != -1)
            addServicePerformed(service, serviceId);
        else
            Log.d("DBTAG", "Error inserting new Service");
    }
}


private void addServicePerformed(VehicleService service, @Nullable Integer serviceId)
{
    SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = getWritableDatabase();

    if (serviceId == null)
    {
        dbWritable.beginTransaction();
        serviceId = getServiceId(service, dbWritable);
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SERVICE_ID, serviceId);
    values.put(ODOMETER_AT_SERVICE, service.getOdometer());
    values.put(DATE_OF_SERVICE, Utility.FormatDate(service.getDate()));
    values.put(COST_OF_SERVICE, service.getCost());

    dbWritable.insert(SERVICE_PERFORMED_TABLE, null, values);

}
```

Doing what @Shree Krishna said worked.